# Did Jesus heal a person with a chromosome defect?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, bible, miracles, healing

Is there anywhere in the bible a hint or something saying Jesus healing someone with a chromosome defect? For example somebody with a Down Syndrome or similar.

What about today's healings? Was it ever recorded a Down Syndrome person miraculously healed?

If not what is the explanation for why this type of handicap God doesn't choose to heal? (for this sentence I need a Catholic view).

Comment: Please remember that the Stack Exchange model is one-specific-question/one-best answer.  By "mental genetic defect" I assume you mean a brain defect vs a nervous system defect or muscular defect?  (I ask because blindness (e.g. "the one born blind") can happen for a variety of reasons - including brain defect.)  Also, Jesus and His followers brought people back from the dead - what makes you assume any disease or defect might not be curable?

Comment: @JBH, I gave you the example(a DS person) and I'm not assuming anything. I edited my question.

Comment: OK, to help set an expectation... A down-syndrome child is active in our congregation. He'd likely have been described as "dumb" by people 2,000 years ago.  He'd have been described as "dumb" by people 200 years ago.  Your question might not be answerable to your satisfaction as the phrase "down syndrome" didn't come into use until the 1970s. Which is a lengthy way of saying "maybe, but we can't know due to the lack of detail provided in the scriptural account." Blind, dumb, and palsied people were healed Biblically - all potentially systemic/genetic conditions. But that's the best we can say.

Comment: @JBH, What about today's healings?

Comment: I'm not Catholic, but that might not matter.  I'm personally unaware of anyone specifically suffering from Down Syndrome having been healed.  But, as an engineer, I know that my lack of knowledge is far from conclusive proof that it hasn't ever happened or can't happen.  (Sorry, the habit of full disclosure - I come from a family full of lawyers.)

Comment: @JBH np. I'm trying to figure why only certain diseases God heals through his ministers. I'm sure there must be a reason.

Comment: That makes sense.  Let me add one more insight.  I've a niece who suffered brain damage due to an auto accident decades ago.  Despite many blessings for healing (and I've personally participated in healing blessings that miraculously healed...) she has never been healed.  Sometimes individuals are healed to show the glory and power of God.  Most often, individuals are not healed to allow others to show their faith in God through service.  The Lord, Himself, healed many - but none simply for the convenience of the afflicted.  It's a heartache I know very well.

Comment: Just a little note of possible interest for Catholics. In order to be canonized, individuals needs a miracle obtained in though their intercession. If any possible miracle in this domain were to occur, I believe that it will be through the intercession of [Professeur  Jérôme Lejeune](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jérôme_Lejeune).

Answer (score 4):

The Bible was written down about two thousand years ago, when nothing was known about "Chromosome defects". So the Bible writers didn't record whether any of the people Jesus healed had chromosome defects. Nor did they give us enough information to work our for ourselves if they had them.

> what is the explanation for why this type of handicap God doesn't choose to heal?

We don't know that he doesn't. If he can raise someone from the dead, he is certainly capable of healing a chromosome defect. Just because it wasn't recorded that Jesus did that in his time on earth doesn't mean he didn't do it, or hasn't done it since.

Comment: The question isn't whether it is a problem for him but whether he did it. And that's a different story. I don't think your reasoning is correct. I'm sure people would be able to distinguish from the physical appearance that this defect is different than any other. They would be able to describe it. I.e. - a dumb person with mongoloid eyes or something similar.

Comment: They might be able to describe it, but considering that Down syndrome wasn't recognized as a specific condition until the 19th century, it's unlikely that they would have described it this way. People thought about diseases and medical conditions differently before the late 19th century than they do now.

Comment: @Grasper My last sentence is addressing the question in your last sentence.

Comment: well I was looking for something that would explain the meaning of why it shouldn't be healed, not whether it is possible.

Comment: You did say 'can't'. I think that would be better off as a separate question.

Comment: @DJClayworth, ok, I changed it so it is more obvious. And only a Catholic explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Indirectly we may draw some inferences

> “He brought them forth also with silver and gold: and there was not one **feeble** person among their tribes.”
> ‭‭Psalms‬ ‭105:37‬ ‭

There being not even one feeble or one who stumbled among an assembly of 6 or 7 figure is highly unlikely. Especially since they were laborers, and it would not be statistically improbable that someone might have fallen during the construction and making of bricks and paralyzed their legs in the course of years leading up to the great exodus.

It appears that all those who ate of the lamb received supernatural healing such that none would stumble or be feeble on this trek to Canaan.

Is it therefore possible that someone had a genetic condition that caused them to stumble requiring healing for this passage to hold true?

> “But when Jesus knew it, he withdrew himself from thence: and great multitudes followed him, and **he healed them all**;”
> ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭12:15‬ ‭

If Jesus healed them ALL, that means all. That means without exception whether they were aware of the cause or not, whether they understood it was genetically related or otherwise, all were healed.

> “Then when Jesus came, he found that he had lain **in the grave four days** already.”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭11:17‬ ‭

Four days in decomposition, putrefaction  means cells, a large percentage of cells are denatured. All these had to be restored which is precisely what would have to happen with a person suffering from trisomy for example

> “And great crowds came to him, bringing with them the lame χωλους , the blind, the crippled κυλλους , the mute, and many others, and they put them at his feet, and he healed them,”
> ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭15:30‬ ‭

The first Greek word χωλους translated lame means maimed, which is a physical injury especially loss of limb. Similar for the second Greek word. Inference being, that Jesus was required to make limbs grow, appear from nothing. If He can make something out of nothing, surely He can remove an extra chromosome or correct a genetic mutation. Especially if the phenotype expression to be corrected requires genetic manipulation.

> “And there was a woman who had had a discharge of blood for twelve years,”
> ‭‭Mark‬ ‭5:25‬ ‭

Haemophilia is an x-linked genetic condition. Not concluding this is what this woman had but if she did, in order for her to be healed here genetic disorder had to be resolved or the pathway blocked somehow.

In conclusion while the text does not clearly state genetic disorders, it speaks of all being healed, it describes, restoration of putrefied cells and even missing limbs. It also speaks of corrections, such as correction of vision, if the eyes can be corrected, then the genes must also be correctable.

Comment: I’m not a Catholic, let me know if you want me to delete this post.